# Expiry date IF santance is not working with MYSQL UPDATE

Tags: php, date

I have table with many rows. I have exp date and I want to change status of those rows where date is already exp.

It work well if I do not use UPDATE. If I just echo them. But when I want to UPDATE status of this row to 0, problems start. My problem is that it change only 1 row and not all of them that needs to be whit status 0.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$id = $row['id'];

if($resultcheck > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$expdate = $row['date'];
$exp = strtotime($date);

$today = date('m/d/Y');
$td = strtotime($today);

if($td>$exp) {
$status=0;

$sql = " UPDATE table SET status = '$status' WHERE ID = '$id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
}
}
```

Any advice how to fix that, I tried several option but nothing worked.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. I don't see any `$id` here, it should be `row[id]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `row['id']` instead of `$id`.

`$sql = " UPDATE table SET status = '$status' WHERE ID = 'row['id']' ";`

2. Rename `$result` for update. You are reusing the same variable name, hence, after a success update, it will set `$result` to **true** and the while loop will stop.

Comment: I have $id = $row['id'];

not working. It change only 1 row.

Comment: WORKING. Thanks